# Cannot iterate through map in print() method

Tags: c++, class, for-loop, iterator, constants

I've done some exercises before where I loop through maps no problem. Now that I'm doing so in a class, I'm getting strange errors that I don't understand at all. It seems to happen at the instantiation of the iterator in the print() method.

> error: conversion from ‘std::mapstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> bool>::const_iterator’ {aka
> ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string, bool> >’} to non-scalar type
> ‘std::mapstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, bool>::iterator’ {aka
> ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const
> std::__cxx11::basic_string, bool> >’} requested    33 |   for
> (map<string, bool>::iterator i = jobs.begin(); i != jobs.end(); i++) {

Here is my code:

```
class Employee {
private:
    string name;
    map<string, bool> jobs;

public:

    Employee() {
        name = "";
        jobs[""] = false;
    }
    
    Employee(const Employee &other) {
        cout << "Copied." << endl;
        name = other.name;
        jobs = other.jobs;
    }

    Employee(string name, string task, bool trained) {
        this->name = name;
        jobs[task] = trained;
    }
    
    void setTask(string task, bool trained) {
        jobs[task] = trained;
    }
    
    void print() const {
        for (map<string, bool>::iterator i = jobs.begin(); i != jobs.end(); i++) {
            pair<string, bool> jobs = *i;
            cout << name << " is trained on " << jobs.first << "? " << jobs.second << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

I promise I did my best to look for solutions online before coming here. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something extremely elementary.

I've tried making the print method const or not const, and I've experimented with using const_iterator and .cbegin()/.cend() in case it was being picky about that. Sadly, I'm just not very good at debugging yet.

Comment: It is better to use auto as an iterator's type since they are usually complex and error-prune.  And from the error message, it seems the variable "i" is a const iterator.

Comment: A range-based for loop would be even better just `auto`'ing the type.

Answer (score 1):

The member function `print` is a constant member function. It means that within the function data members of the class are constants. So instead of `map<string, bool>::iterator` you need to use `map<string, bool>::const_iterator`

Also it is a bad idea to redeclare the name `jobs` within the for loop. And moreover this declaration is redundant.

You should write

```
void print() const {
    for (map<string, bool>::const_iterator i = jobs.cbegin(); i != jobs.cend(); i++) {
        cout << name << " is trained on " << i->first << "? " << i->second << endl;
    }
}
```

If your compiler supports C++ 17 then you could use range-based for loop the following way

```
void print() const {
    for ( const auto &[first, second] : jobs ) {
        cout << name << " is trained on " << first << "? " << second << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `print` member function is declared as `const`, so all occurrences/uses of data members of the class made within it will also be treated as `const`.

Thus, the calls to `jobs.begin()` and `jobs.end()` will invoke the `const` overloads of [those functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin), which have return types of `const_iterator`. So, to fix your issue, make `i` a `const_iterator`:

```cpp
    void print() const {
        for (map<string, bool>::const_iterator i = jobs.begin(); i != jobs.end(); i++) {
            pair<string, bool> localjob = *i; // Avoid "shadowing" member variable!
            cout << name << " is trained on " << localjob.first << "? " << localjob.second << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void print() const
```

That `const` in the end means that this class method is a `const` class method. It can be called on `const` instances of this class. What it means is that, as far as this method is concerned, all members of its class are `const`.

```
map<string, bool>::iterator i = jobs.begin();
```

Since `this` is `const`, the `begin()` overload returns a `const_iterator`, instead of `iterator`, and that's the reason for your compilation error.

> I've tried making the print method const or not const,

But what you haven't tried to do is use the current C++ standard, you are apparently using a very, very outdated textbook to learn C++. Current C++ makes all of this much easier:

```
   void print() const {
        for (auto &job:jobs)
            cout << name << " is trained on " << job.first << "? " << job.second << endl;
        }
```

And that's not even the best way to do it. I'll leave it to you to get your textbook updated, and learn about structured bindings that makes this even cleaner to read.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong (and your last code snippet works in this, specific case) but using   a reference as the loop variable will carry the constness into `job`. If the OP (in their real-world code) wanted to mess around with the local (loop) variable, then a non-reference would more closely emulate their **copying** via the `*i`.

Comment: Thank you for this. The course I'm using may not be completely current, you're right. I'm getting an error and I can't tell if it is related, or if it is a completely different problem.
`error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const Employee’ and ‘const Employee’)
  386 |       { return __x < __y; }
`

Comment: This is a different issue somewhere else in your program. This is, again, related to a basic principle that should be covered in every C++ textbook.

Comment: Got it. I was missing a comparison operator. Learning a lot today! Thanks again.